# List all issues in a Github project (with GraphQL)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, github, graphql

I'm trying to make a list of GitHub issue titles within a project. To do that I'm using the GraphQL API. There was no trouble with this when I had < 100 issues, (one page) but now that there are over 100, I need to get multiple pages, which means I need to recursively call the function.

The problem is that since it's asynchronous I'm not sure how to make that final list. I need one array with all titles, so that I can alphabetize it and output it. The best I can do now is alphabetize each chunk.

```
function buildIssueList(cursor){
    var title_list = [];
    var url = graphqlapi;
    var query = "";
    if (cursor == ""){
        query = 'query { repository(owner:”me”, name:”myrepo”) { projects(first: 10) { edges { node { name columns(first: 10) { nodes { name cards(first: 100) { totalCount edges { node { content { ... on Issue { title } } } cursor } pageInfo { endCursor hasNextPage } } } } } } } } }';
    }
    else {
        query = 'query { repository(owner:"me", name:"myrepo") { projects(first: 10) { edges { node { name columns(first: 10) { nodes { name cards(first: 100, after:' + '\"' + cursor + '\"' + ') { totalCount edges { node { content { ... on Issue { title } } } cursor } pageInfo { endCursor hasNextPage } } } } } } } } }';
    } 
    var data = {'query': query}
    var column_list = []
    var mresponse = $.ajax({
        headers: {
            Authorization: "Bearer mytoken"
        },
        dataType: "json",
        type: 'POST',
        url: url,
        data: JSON.stringify(data)
        }).done(function(data) {
            data["data"]['repository']['projects']['edges'].forEach(function(entry) {
                if (entry["node"]["name"] == “myprojectname”){
                    column_list = entry["node"]["columns"]["nodes"];
                }
            });
            column_list.forEach(function(column) {
                if (column["cards"]["pageInfo"]["hasNextPage"] == true) {
                    var tempar = [];
                    column["cards"]["edges"].forEach(function(node) {
                        tempar.push(node["node"]["content"]["title"]);
                    });
                    addtoDropdown(tempar);
                    var next_cursor = column["cards"]["pageInfo"]["endCursor"];
                    buildIssueList(next_cursor);

                } else {
                    var ftempar = [];
                    column["cards"]["edges"].forEach(function(node) {
                        ftempar.push(node["node"]["content"]["title"]);
                    });
                    addtoDropdown(ftempar);
                }
            });
        });
}
```

"addtoDropdown()" alphabetizes the array it's passed and adds it to the master list. And, I don't want to just continuously alphabetize the master list for the duration of my program. I want to make my full list, and alphabetize it once.